# Programmatically change background / source for ImageView in android

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-file, android-bitmap

I am creating an android app where I want to display an image full screen. The image is stored in the internal storage of an android phone and the image to be displayed can vary each time. In the layout XML file for that activity, I added an image view tag as shown below:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:src="@drawable/android" />
```

What shall I type for the `android:src` ? Any help & suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: use java code instead of xml for setting source from sd card.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Optional: Remove the line

```
android:src="@drawable/android"
//This can be kept as a default image in case the file you want does not exist.
```

from the XML layout. Since the image may vary every time, you need to use

```
File file = new  File("/sdcard/Images/test_image.jpg");

if(file.exists()){

    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getAbsolutePath());

    ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageview1);

    image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

}
```

Comment: `Remove the line...` - not needed- You can use this to show a **default image**.

Comment: No matter. +1 for both of you - The answers are very similar and given in the same time (so, I'm sure no one copied from the other one).

Answer (score 2):

try the below code to set Bitmap images from a file stored inside a SD-Card .

```
File imgFile = new  File("/sdcard/Images/test_image.jpg");

if(imgFile.exists()){

    Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());

    ImageView myImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageviewTest);

    myImage.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);

}
```

this works at runtime

Answer (score 1):

You can do this at runtime, Try This:

```
String pathName = "/sdcard/abc.png";
Resources res = getResources();
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(pathName);
BitmapDrawable bd = new BitmapDrawable(res, bitmap);
ImageView view = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.container);
view.setBackgroundDrawable(bd);
```